# Can a nullable variable in C# be marked as non-null from some point on for the compiler?

Tags: c#, nullable, optional-parameters

I use `null` to denote that an optional parameter `A? a` of a function should assume a non-null default value, computed in the function. After entering the function, I check whether the passed-in argument `a` is `null`, and if so, assign `a` a non-null value. From that point on, it can safely be assumed that `a` is non-null. The problem: the compiler is not aware of this, and now I have to refer to `a.Value` for the rest of the function, instead of the straightforward `a`.

Is there a way to tell the compiler that `a` is actually non-null from some point on? If not, what is the clearest way to deal with such optional parameters?

Example code:

```
using System;

namespace test
{

    public struct A { public int x; };

    class Program
    {

        static void f(A? a = null)
        {
            // Assign the default value.
            if (a == null) a = new A { x = 3 };
            // Now 'a' is non-null for the rest of the function.
            // What I do now:
            Console.WriteLine(a.Value.x);
            // What I'd like to do:
            // * Mark 'a' as non-null somehow.
            // Now can refer to 'a' directly:
            // Console.WriteLine(a.x);
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            f();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Introduce a new non-nullable variable: `A notNull = a ?? new A { x = 3 };` and use that in the remainder of the method (presumably with a better name than `notNull` ...)

Comment: That's another approach, but I'd like to avoid that.

Comment: This isn't to do with the compiler unfortunately: `A?` means `Nullable<A>`, and `Nullable<T>` has the property `Value`. As long as you've got a variable of type `Nullable<T>`, you still need to access its `Value` property to get the value it contains

Comment: At least in C# 10 the compiler already understands that `a` is no longer `null` when it gets to the `Console.WriteLine` statement. If I comment out the if-statement, I get a warning that `a` may be null, but that warning is not there with the if-statement present. BUT! `a` is still typed as `Nullable<A>`, which means you cannot get away from `a.Value` unless you actually extract the `A` instance into a separate variable.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I made that same mistake - in fact, the OP wants to use `Console.WriteLine(a.x)` which of course won't compile.

Comment: Yep, but the compiler both does and doesn't do what he wants. The compiler in fact marks `a` as "Not null" for the remainder of that method, but it doesn't change its type so it doesn't unwrap the `Nullable<T>`. It just gets rid of warnings about potential null values from the rest of the method.

Comment: Yep. I misunderstood the meaning of `A?`; it is clear to me now that `a.x` should not compile. Seems like I'm getting two problems solved for one!

Comment: For those interested, my confusion came from TypeScript, where you can have a type `A | null`, and things work as I thought they would work above. [Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G9oChpugBwK4CMQEthoAPaAXmgAYBuZAX2WQDMsA7YAF3wHtXomAFGGgAuaAPgAfaKywgQASnIy5ixKnT4m44WQqz5S3YlJiAzHVrpowXhG4gApgDoQ3AOZDnxBbQbMBXwCDRVpBBFNoABY6BUY0IA)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you just want to allow the method to be called without specifying a parameter (and use a certain default in that case).

There is another possible solution to this particular scenario:. Just overload `f()` like so:

```
static void f()
{
    f(new A { x = 3 });
}

static void f(A a)
{
    Console.WriteLine(a.x);
}
```

Code can then call `f()` with or without a parameter, but the difference is that in the case where it calls `f(A a)` with a parameter, it cannot be null.

---

(In response to your comment below.)

If you want to handle being able to call with a possibly-null struct, you can overload like this instead:

```
static void f(A? a = default)
{
    f(a ?? new A { x = 3 });
}

static void f(A a)
{
    Console.WriteLine(a.x);
}
```

That means your implementation doesn't have to deal with a possibly-null value, but you can still omit the argument at the call site, or call it with a null value.

Note: You can simplify `static void f(A? a = default)` to:

```
static void f(A? a = default) => f(a ?? new A { x = 3 });
```

if you prefer the shorter syntax.

Comment: This is also something that I sometimes do. However, there are cases where I am forwarding a possibly null parameter (so that I don't know whether it is null), and in that case this does not work; i.e. the one with optional parameter is a more general approach.

Comment: @kaba See my edit.

Comment: That latter edit is an interesting approach.

Comment: This answer pretty much seems to hit the nail on my problem; i.e. to have optional parameters with default values, handle them as if non-null (because they now are), and without having to invent extraneous variable-names. Nice work!

Answer (score 6):

No, there isn't - not for a nullable *value* type. The compile-time type of a nullable value type is still `Nullable<T>`, even if the compiler knows that it will be non-null.

This is different from nullable *reference* types where the compiler keeps track of whether it thinks the variable may be null in order to warn about dereferencing. With nullable reference types, there are no "real" separate nullable and non-nullable types - just the single reference type with an indication of whether the value might be null.

The approach of introducing a new non-nullable variable as given in comments on the question is really the only way forward here.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use properties for this.

With properties, you can assign fields to new values, and make sure these properties either return the expected value, or a default value.

Like this:

```
int? a = null;

public int a2
{
    get
    {
        return a.GetValueOrDefault(3);
    }
}
```

Then you can use property `a2` instead of `a`

Not exactly the same as changing a field from nullable to non-nullable, but it may do the thing that you expected to do.

Answer (score -1):

No, it cannot be done. `A?` is a shortcut for `Nullable<A>`. `Nullable<A>` is clearly a different type to `A`, and in order to get the value, you need to use `Nullable<A>.Value`.

The best option you have is, as was commented by @MatthewWatson, to introduce another variable:

```
A aValue = a ?? new A { x = 3 };
```

Something that can help is to properly name the parameter and the actual value being used, to help differentiate them:

```
static void f(A? optionalA = null)
{
    // Use optionalA if it has a value, or the default value otherwise.
    var a = optionalA ?? new A { x = 3 };
```

Comment: Naming is hard:( If the caller uses named parameters as in `f(optionalA : new A {x = 4})`, then the optional-prefix is just noise to the caller. So perhaps the interface should keep the clear name `a`, and the implementation should take the hit instead. Sometimes I name the new variable in the implementation `a_`, i.e. with underscore.